# Using TextBoxes Text after creating them in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF page with a wrappanel , 
one button to genrate Textboxes in the wrappanel with text in them
and one button to get the text that was written into the textboxes.
Her's the xaml part :

```html
<StackPanel>
        <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="WP1"
                   Height="200"/>
        <Button Content="Insert" Click="Button_Click" Margin="10"/>
        <Button Content="Get_TextBoxes_Text" x:Name="GetTextBoxes_Txt_btn"
                Click="GetTextBoxes_Txt_btn_Click" Margin="10"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

Now when each time i click on the first button, it create a textbox into the wrappanel with a text. Let's say that i've clicked 3 times (but it can be 1 or 2 or 10...) on the button .

```
  private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox t = new TextBox()
        {
            Text = "100",
            Padding = new Thickness(3),
            BorderBrush = Brushes.Black
        };
        WP1.Children.Add(t);
        // Let's imagine i've clicked 3 times on this button to create 3 textboxes. But the user will be able to click from 1 to 10 times, we don't know at this point.
    }
```

Now when i click on the second button, i want to concat in a string each textbox text that we're created like :

```
 private void GetTextBoxes_Txt_btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // How to get into a string the content of the 3 textboxes like :
        string text = first_TextBox.Text + secondTextBox.Text + thirdTextBox.Text //????
    }
```

But of course this doesn't work because the textboxes i've created do not have a "real" name.
How can i deal with it ?
Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [VisualTreeHelper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper?view=netcore-3.1) to iterate all children of your control. For each `TextBox` you can get and concatenate the text like this sample:

```
string text = "";
int childNumber = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(WP1);
for (int i = 0; i <= childNumber - 1; i++)
{
    DependencyObject child = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(WP1, i);
    if (child is TextBox textBox)
    {
        text += textBox.Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, i've tried your code. I've created one textbox that content "119" and another that content "121". The i've put the result of your code in a messageBox to see how it looks like. And i get one textbox with "119" (click ok) and another with "191121". I don(t need the first one actually.

Comment: Looks like you are showing the message for each entry in the loop. Just do it once after the for loop.